# How to automatically document database changes in DevOps Deployment Pipeline

Tags: sql, database, devops, dacpac, change-tracking

I have been looking for a way to automatically document changes made to a SQL Database (i.e. based on its dacpac) while deploying the solution through Azure Deployment Pipelines.

For example if I move a table to another schema or add a column I would like to receive a list / document that includes:

```
Before:
TableName:
dbo.Something
Colums: A INT, B INT, C NVARCHAR

After
TableName:
abc.Something
Columns: A INT, B DECIMAL, C INT, D NVARCHAR
```

I've searched through the available jobs and tasks of the Azure deployment pipeline / task groups and researched the topic without success.